# Any package for typesetting polyominos/tetris-like shapes?

Tags: polyomino, puzzle, tetris

I would like to typeset some easy polyomino puzzles and therefore need a suitable LaTeX package. I could not find an easy to use package (other than using TikZ of course). Is there any approach other than using TikZ/PSTricks?

For anybody not aware of what polyominos are:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino

Edit:
With a polyomino puzzle, I mean something like this:
http://www.virtualimage.co.uk/html/polyomino.html

So my intention is to put a set of polyominos into a given shape.

Comment: Any such package would in turn use TikZ/PSTricks, and probably have a very TikZ/MP-like interface.  If you can make a polyomino with TikZ, then I suggest you simply write such a package, as one does not appear to exist.

Comment: @SeanAllred I believe that this is more a question of a _good user interface_ than of the programming layer. Many LaTeX packages could witness that.

Comment: @tohecz than perhaps, in the complete absence of any extant package, a ideal user interface should be defined.  I find it difficult to envision a consistent interface that would cover all the different configurations of every polyomino.

Comment: @SeanAllred; I think you are probably right. Since there are already 35 free forms for a polyomino of 6 blocks, it will be difficult to provide some intuitive way of specifying them with single commands. Would be an interesting idea for a package though.

Comment: Oh! Oh! I like creating interfaces. A sequence of the form `s[lrud]+` (start, left, right, up, down) can supply the shape of a polyomino. Like `surdru` for a 2-by-3 block. Use capital letters to create anchors. So `SurdrU` has the lower left and upper right blocks as anchors, identified by `1` and `2` respectively. Two should be enough to position any 2-dimensional shape if we don't allow mirroring. This kind of specification allows overlapping blocks. That's on purpose, so you can specify a + shape with `sudrldul`. The code should catch overlapping-errors on placement. Just a thought.

Comment: The problem is indeed not the typesetting, but the interface. David Carlisle's answer doesn't use any graphics package, just rules. But the interface doesn't seem very user friendly to me.

Comment: @Toscho One could think of other interfaces but just drawing the pattern seemed the easiest I could think of. (You don't have to lay it out on multiple lines `*\\*\\*` eould make a vertical 3 and `***` would make a horizontal one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: My comment wasn't meant as a critique. I simply used your answer as an example for the difference between the user friendliness and easiness to implement of the interface.

Comment: @Toscho no offence taken:-)

Comment: Great, it seems like there is a huge interest in this problem :-) My request more or less asks for a generic way to create specific polyominos (of course it would be nice if they could be loaded via the package). The answeres so far draw polyominos but to not put them into a square (the usual polyomino puzzle type). If there is a way to do this, it should be possible to wrap it into a package.

Comment: @user26372 “Put them into a square”? What do you mean? Please [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/110248/edit) your question and include what you actually want! Define a user interface if you are not happy with the answers.

Comment: Imagine you are given a set of polyominos and need to figure out how to fit them into a given shape, e.g., a square or some other shape. You may have a look at the two examples shown here: http://www.virtualimage.co.uk/html/polyomino.html

Comment: Have a look at Donald Knuth's [metapost program](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs/polyomino.mp) for drawing polyominos.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Code 1

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{qrr@tikz@omino}
\newcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@up}
\newcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@right}
\tikzset{
    omino/.style={/tikz/omino/.cd,#1},
    omino/distance/.initial=1,
    omino/radius/.initial=.5,
    omino/at/.style={/tikz/shift={(#1)}},
    omino/rotate/.style={/tikz/rotate=#1},
    omino/s/.code=
        \setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino}{0}%
        \setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@up}{0}%
        \setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@right}{0}%
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/insert path={(0,0) node[/tikz/omino/nodes/.try,/tikz/omino/node normal/.try,/tikz/omino/node start/.try] {\qrr@tikz@omino@text@start}}},
    omino/u/.code=%
        \stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino}%
        \stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@up}%
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/insert path={
            to[/tikz/omino/how] ++(up:#1)
            node[/tikz/omino/nodes/.try,/tikz/omino/node normal/.try,/tikz/omino/node up/.try]{\qrr@tikz@omino@text@up}}},
    omino/d/.code=%
        \stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino}%
        \addtocounter{qrr@tikz@omino@up}{-1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/insert path={
            to[/tikz/omino/how] ++(down:#1)
            node[/tikz/omino/nodes/.try,/tikz/omino/node normal/.try,/tikz/omino/node down/.try]{\qrr@tikz@omino@text@down}}},
    omino/l/.code=%
        \stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino}%
        \addtocounter{qrr@tikz@omino@right}{-1}%
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/insert path={
            to[/tikz/omino/how] ++(left:#1)
            node[/tikz/omino/nodes/.try,/tikz/omino/node normal/.try,/tikz/omino/node left/.try]{\qrr@tikz@omino@text@left}}},
    omino/r/.code=%
        \stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino}%
        \stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@right}%
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/insert path={
            to[/tikz/omino/how] ++(right:#1)
            node[/tikz/omino/nodes/.try,/tikz/omino/node normal/.try,/tikz/omino/node right/.try] {\qrr@tikz@omino@text@right}}},
    omino/u/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/omino/distance},
    omino/d/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/omino/distance},
    omino/l/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/omino/distance},
    omino/r/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/omino/distance},
    omino/how/.style=,
    omino/reset/.code=
        \pgfutil@in@_{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@
            \qrr@tikz@omino@split#1\relax
        \else
            \edef\pgf@tempa{\csname qrr@tikz@omino@coords@#1\endcsname}%
            \expandafter\qrr@tikz@omino@split\pgf@tempa\relax
        \fi
        \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/insert path={(omino-n-#1.center) node[/tikz/omino/nodes/.try, /tikz/omino/node reset/.try] {\qrr@tikz@omino@text@reset}}},
    omino/do/.code={\@tfor\@next:=#1\do{\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/omino/\@next}}},
    omino/node reset/.style={draw=none,fill=none},
    omino/node normal/.style={
        name=omino-n-\number\c@qrr@tikz@omino,
        alias=omino-n-\number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@right_\number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@up,
        omino/@store coords
    },
    omino/@store coords/.code=
        \expandafter\xdef\csname qrr@tikz@omino@coords@\arabic{qrr@tikz@omino}\endcsname
        {\number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@right_\number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@up},
    omino/Text/.code 2 args=\expandafter\edef\csname qrr@tikz@omino@text@#1\endcsname{#2},
    omino/Text={up}{},omino/Text={down}{},omino/Text={left}{},omino/Text={right}{},omino/Text={start}{},omino/Text={reset}{}
}
\def\qrr@tikz@omino@split#1_#2\relax{\setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@right}{#1}\setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@up}{#2}}

\tikzset{
    omino/x mirror/.style={/tikz/cm={-1,0,0,1,(0,0)}},
    omino/y mirror/.style={/tikz/cm={1,0,0,-1,(0,0)}}
}

\tikzset{fun/.code={\pgfmathtruncatemacro\@fun{\number\c@qrr@tikz@omino/4*100}\pgfkeysalso{fill=blue!\@fun!red}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
    tetris/.style={/tikz/tetris/.cd,#1},
    tetris/1/.style={/tikz/omino={do=suuu}},
    tetris/2/.style={/tikz/omino={do=suur}},
    tetris/2'/.style={/tikz/omino/x mirror, 2},
    tetris/3/.style={/tikz/omino={do=suru}},
    tetris/3'/.style={/tikz/omino/x mirror, 3},
    tetris/4/.style={/tikz/omino={do=surd}},
    tetris/5/.style={/tikz/omino={s,u,u,reset=1,r}}
}
\makeatletter

\makeatother
\newcommand*{\thesamepictureeverywhere}{\matrix[column sep=.5cm, row sep=.5cm, ampersand replacement=\&] {
\path [tetris=1];  \&
\path [tetris=2']; \& \path [tetris=2]; \\
\path [tetris=3];  \& \path [tetris=3']; \&
\path [tetris=4];  \&
\path [tetris=5];\\};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every path/.style=draw,
    omino/how/.style={bend left},
    omino/nodes/.style={circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt, fill=black, outer sep=+0pt}]
\thesamepictureeverywhere
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[omino/nodes/.style={rectangle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1cm, draw}]
\thesamepictureeverywhere
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[omino={
        nodes/.style={circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1cm, draw},
        Text={left}l,Text={right}r,Text={up}u,Text={down}d,Text={start}s
        }]
\thesamepictureeverywhere
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[omino/nodes/.style={shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1cm, fun}]
\thesamepictureeverywhere
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    tetris/1/.prefix style={/tikz/omino/nodes/.append style={fill=black,text=white}},
    tetris/2/.prefix style={/tikz/omino/nodes/.append style={fill=blue}},
    tetris/3/.prefix style={/tikz/omino/nodes/.append style={fill=green!70!blue}},
    tetris/4/.prefix style={/tikz/omino/nodes/.append style={fill=yellow!80!black}},
    tetris/5/.prefix style={/tikz/omino/nodes/.append style={fill=red!70!black}},
    omino/Text={start}{.}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[omino/nodes/.style={shape=rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=1cm-2\pgflinewidth}]
    \path [tetris=1];
    \path [omino/at=0:1] [tetris=2];
    \path [omino/at=0:2] [tetris=3];
    \path [omino={at=0:3, rotate=-90, x mirror}][tetris=5];
    \path [omino={at={5,1}, rotate=-90}][tetris=3];
    \path [omino={at={5,2}, rotate=-90}][tetris=2];
    \path [omino={at={4,2}, x mirror}][tetris=5];
    \path [omino={at={1,3}}][tetris=4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output 1

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Code 2

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    omino/.style={/tikz/omino.cd,#1},
    omino/row sep/.initial=1cm,
    omino/column sep/.initial=1cm}
\newcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@y}
\newcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@x}
\def\qrr@tikz@omino@empty{\stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@x}}
\def\qrr@tikz@omino@full{%
    \stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@x}
    \node[
        every omino node/.try,
        every omino row \number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@y/.try,
        every omino column \number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@x/.try,
        every omino cell \number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@x-\number\c@qrr@tikz@omino@y/.try,
        at={(\c@qrr@tikz@omino@x*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/omino/column sep},\c@qrr@tikz@omino@y*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/omino/row sep})}
        ]{};}
\def\qrr@tikz@omino@nextrow{\setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@x}{0}\stepcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@y}}
\def\qrr@tikz@omino@final{\endgroup\@gobble}
\def\qrr@omino{%
    \afterassignment\qrr@@omino\let\qrr@next@token=}
\def\qrr@@omino{%
    \let\qrr@next\relax
    \ifx\qrr@next@token.%
        \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@omino@empty
    \else
        \ifx\qrr@next@token*%
            \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@omino@full
        \else
            \ifx\qrr@next@token:
                \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@omino@nextrow
            \else
                \ifx\qrr@next@token;
                    \let\qrr@next\qrr@tikz@omino@final
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    \qrr@next\qrr@omino
}
\newcommand*{\omino}[1][]{\begingroup\tikzset{#1}\setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@x}{0}\setcounter{qrr@tikz@omino@y}{0}\qrr@omino}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every omino node/.style={circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every omino node/.append style={rectangle, fill,draw}]
\matrix[column sep=.5cm]{
\omino *:*:*:*; & \omino **:*:*; & \omino *:**:*; & \omino .*:**:*; \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every omino row 0/.style={fill=blue},
    every omino row 1/.style={fill=blue!33!red},
    every omino row 2/.style={fill=blue!67!red},
    every omino row 3/.style={fill=red}]
\matrix[column sep=.5cm]{
\omino *:*:*:*; & \omino **:*:*; & \omino *:**:*; & \omino .*:**:*; \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you insert `onimo/A/.style={/tikz/insert path={coordinate[/tikz/onimo/how](#1)}},` into the `tikzset`? That way, one can easily define an anchor via A=anchorname, and jump back to it via `reset`?

Comment: @Toscho In my updated answer, nodes are named consecutively `omino-n-<counter>` and `omino-n-<right>-<up>` where `<counter>` increments from `0`, and `<right>` and `<up>` are the position in relation to the first node. These names can be used for reset (either `1` or `0_1` in the last case).

Comment: This definitely exceeds my Tikz skills :-) The only thing left is a grid to actually place the polyominos (so it is a puzzle or a tetris game).

Comment: @user26372 I have extended my first code and added an alternative. In both solutions, you can place these polyominos with `at` (first solution, uses `shift` internally) or `shift` (both solutions). In the first solution you can re-define the path, so that the start coordinate lies more in the middle tiles … It ultimately comes down to how you want to input these figures and where you want to use them …

Comment: I edited my question to address that a little better. Hope you get what I mean. But your solution (especially the last example of your first piece of code) is already very close to what I was hoping for.

Comment: This is a really nice answer!

Comment: +1 although picture mode will recover to fight another day:-)

Answer (score 15):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\omino#1{{%
\unitlength10\p@
\@tempcnta\z@
\@tempcntb\@ne
\count@\z@
\xomino#1\relax
\fbox{\begin{picture}(\@tempcnta,\@tempcntb)(0,-\@tempcntb)%
\@tempcnta\z@
\@tempcntb\@ne
\count@\z@
\xxomino#1\relax
\end{picture}}%
}%
}

\def\xomino#1{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
\ifx\\#1%
\ifnum\count@>\@tempcnta \@tempcnta\count@\fi
\advance\@tempcntb\@ne
\count@\z@
\else
\advance\count@\@ne
\fi
\expandafter\xomino
\fi}

\def\xxomino#1{%
\ifx\relax#1%
\else
  \ifx\\#1%
    \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
    \count@\z@
  \else
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \ifx*#1%
      \put(\count@,-\@tempcntb){\kern-10pt\rule{10pt}{10pt}}%
    \fi
  \fi
\expandafter\xxomino
\fi}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\omino{
*\\
*\\
*\\
*\\
*}

\omino{
**\\
.*\\
.*\\
.*}

\omino{
**\\
*\\
*\\
**}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. You're very quick. :-) But this doesn't allow you to interlock multiple polyominos into a puzzle (with visually distinct pieces). I put my thoughts on a possible interface for that in a comment above. I don't have the time to actually implement it, though.

Comment: Addendum: [click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMAIqZatptY) and enjoy. `:)`

Comment: @mhelvens it's just picture mode so the pieces can be placed in interlocking position (the `\fbox` around the outside is just for debugging really) , if you want thin gaps to show the original squares then you can reduce the size of the rule from 10pt so it is smaller than the coordinate spacing.

Comment: I very much like the way how you create the polyominos. Is it possible to put them into a puzzle (grid), too?

Comment: @user26372 sure you can place them in a picture mode, but as I indicated in the comments  You'd need to adjust teh definition a bit so that it leaves gaps otherwise if you tile an area you'll get a single black rectangle. I'll post something in a bit

Comment: A solution without loading any packages; very nice!

Comment: Agreed.  To get a puzzle, you can use different colours or shades.  So after the \ifx*#1 ... \fi part put some \ifx r#1 ... \fi groups (or nest them if you like) so that it recognises symbols r,g,b, etc and produces colour blocks.  To have it recognise borders requires more work, as David says.

Comment: I have two small issues with this code. I asked about it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519667/code-for-rendering-polyominoes-incorrect-for-one-row

Answer (score 4):

David's solution converts ascii art into graphics.  Here is a derived version that does a similar trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newdimen\omsq  \omsq=20pt
\newdimen\omrule    \omrule=2pt
\newdimen\omint

\newif\ifvth    \newif\ifhth    \newif\ifomblank
\def\OMINO#1{%
    \vthtrue \hthtrue
    \vbox{ \offinterlineskip\parindent=0pt \OM#1\relax\vskip1pt}}


\def\OM#1{%
    \omint=\omsq    \advance\omint-\omrule
    \ifx\relax#1%
    \else
      \ifx\\#1 \newline\null \hthtrue \ifvth\vthfalse\else\vskip-\omrule\vthtrue\fi
      \else%
        \ifx .#1\hskip\ifhth \omrule\else \omint\fi
        \else%
          \ifx +#1\def\colour{black}\fi%
          \ifx -#1\def\colour{black}\fi%
          \ifx |#1\def\colour{black}\fi%
          \ifx @#1\def\colour{black}\fi%
          \ifx r#1\def\colour{red}\fi%
          \ifx g#1\def\colour{green}\fi%
          \ifx b#1\def\colour{blue}\fi%
          \ifx y#1\def\colour{yellow}\fi%
          \ifx m#1\def\colour{magenta}\fi%
          \ifx c#1\def\colour{cyan}\fi%
          \textcolor{\colour}{\rule{\ifhth\omrule\else\omsq\fi}{\ifvth\omrule\else\omsq\fi}}%
          \ifhth\else\hskip -\omrule\fi%
        \fi%
        \ifhth\hthfalse\else\hthtrue\fi%
      \fi%
    \expandafter\OM%
    \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\OMINO{
+-+-----+\\
|g|@|r.r|\\
|.+-+.+-+\\
|g.g|r|.|\\
+-+.|.|.|\\
|c|g|r|.|\\
|.+-+-+.|\\
|c.c.c|.|\\
+-----+-+
}

\OMINO{
+-+.......+-----+\\
|.|.......|r.r.r|\\
|.+-+-----+---+.|\\
|...|y.y.y.y.y|r|\\
+-+.+-+-----+-+.|\\
..|...|.....|r.r|\\
..+---+.....+---+
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Love it. So many great answers!

Comment: I tried putting one of these into a figure environment, but the last row becomes displaced when the figure is centered. I can add an extra line so the row is in the correct position, but even then the figure won't be properly centered.

Comment: @URL this is strange.  The \vbox{} at the outermost level of \OMINO should stop any higher-level environments messing with anything.  Can you post a MWE?

Comment: @AndrewKepert MWE is simply the above code, but one of the OMINOs is enclosed in a figure environment. The figure is then centered via the \centering command.

Comment: Ah OK I see what is going on -  \OMINO is all typeset as though it's a paragraph, and assumes consistent left margins — in particular \leftskip should be non-stretchy.  But \centering which uses stretchy glue for both \leftskip and \rightskip.  The last line gets broken by how TeX finishes paragraphs.  The disaster is not limited to the last line, in that if you have an \OMINO pattern with lines of different lengths, then they will individually be centred.  Fix: `\begin{figure}\begin{centering}\begin{minipage}{7cm}\OMINO{... }\end{minipage}\end{centering}\end{figure}`

Answer (score 3):

May be something like this in crude form

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{picture}(200,200)(120,120)
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
    \rule[0\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{20\unitlength}\rule[0\unitlength]{20\unitlength}{10\unitlength}
    \rule[0\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{20\unitlength}\rule[10\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{20\unitlength}
    \rule[0\unitlength]{20\unitlength}{10\unitlength}\rule[10\unitlength]{20\unitlength}{10\unitlength}
    \rule[0\unitlength]{20\unitlength}{10\unitlength}\rule[0\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{30\unitlength}
    \rule[0\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{30\unitlength}\rule[10\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{10\unitlength}
    \rule[0\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{20\unitlength}\rule[-20\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{20\unitlength}
    \rule[0\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{20\unitlength}\rule[10\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{10\unitlength}\rule[0\unitlength]{10\unitlength}{20\unitlength}
    \end{picture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proposal for an interface:

d is a digit from 1 to 9
coordinate=d_nd_{n-1}d_{n-2}…d_2d_1 is a number out of digits (without 0)
pattern=number is a number, in which each digit may appear at most once and 0 not at all

A polyomino is given by a dictionary with coordinates as keys and patterns as value. What does it mean?

Imagine a keyboard number pad or a telephone number pad. The digits 1-9 are arranged in a 3x3 grid. The digits above all identify one such cell of a 3x3 grid.
The pattern is a number. Each digit occuring in the number means, that the identified cell is part of the polyomino.

Now polyominos can be larger than a 3x3-pattern. So we can arrange 3x3 of these 3x3-patterns into a 3x3 meta-pattern. The position of the pattern in this meta-pattern is specified by the digit d_1 of the coordinate. To get even larger, we can put 3x3 meta-patterns into a meta-meta-pattern. The position inside this meta-meta-pattern is specified by d_2. And so on.

Shorthands:
coordinate=0 means, the last digit in coordinate is not d_1 but d_0 specifying the cell inside the pattern located at the coordinate created from the previous digits of coordinate.

0=pattern means, that the whole polyomino fits into one 3x3-pattern and is described by pattern.

So some examples: (with the base pattern being
789
456
123)

- f-pentomino is `0=24589`
- N-pentomino is `(1=1478,4=2)`
- I-dekomino is `(11=123,12=123,13=123,21=1)`