# Code for rendering polyominoes incorrect for one row

Tags: polyomino

I am using code (very slightly) adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110288/11441) to render polyominoes. It works great except for two issues.

1. The length of polyominoes with only one row does not seem to be taken into account.
2. The second issue is that I always need to fill the first row with spacers for the spacing to work correctly. (This is only an inconvenience, so not as critical as the first issue).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\omino#1{{%
        \unitlength6\p@
        \@tempcnta\z@
        \@tempcntb\@ne
        \count@\z@
        \xomino#1\relax
        \begin{picture}(\@tempcnta,\@tempcntb)(0,-\@tempcntb)%
        \@tempcnta\z@
        \@tempcntb\@ne
        \count@\z@
        \xxomino#1\relax
        \end{picture}%
    }%
}

\def\xomino#1{%
    \ifx\relax#1%
    \else
    \ifx\\#1%
    \ifnum\count@>\@tempcnta \@tempcnta\count@\fi
    \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
    \count@\z@
    \else
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \fi
    \expandafter\xomino
    \fi}

\def\xxomino#1{%
    \ifx\relax#1%
    \else
    \ifx\\#1%
    \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
    \count@\z@
    \else
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \ifx*#1%
    \put(\count@,-\@tempcntb){\kern-6pt\framebox(0.93,0.93)}
    \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\xxomino
    \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Polyominoes with two or more rows like this \omino{*****\\*\\*} 
work great, but polyominoes that have only one row like this 
\omino{******} don't align properly. 

Also, the first row needs to be complete, like this \omino{*...\\****} 
to work. Without the empty characters, the polyomino is not spaced 
correctly, like \omino{*\\****}this. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the computation of the maximum horizontal steps does not take into account the last row. One can fix this by adding the maximum computation in the `\\` case to the `\relax` case. The change is marked with a `%<-`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\omino#1{{%
        \unitlength6\p@
        \@tempcnta\z@
        \@tempcntb\@ne
        \count@\z@
        \xomino#1\relax
        \begin{picture}(\@tempcnta,\@tempcntb)(0,-\@tempcntb)%
        \@tempcnta\z@
        \@tempcntb\@ne
        \count@\z@
        \xxomino#1\relax
        \end{picture}%
    }%
}

\def\xomino#1{%
    \ifx\relax#1%
    \ifnum\count@>\@tempcnta \@tempcnta\count@\fi%<-
    \else
    \ifx\\#1%
    \ifnum\count@>\@tempcnta \@tempcnta\count@
    \fi
    \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
    \count@\z@
    \else
    \advance\count@\@ne%
    \fi
    \expandafter\xomino
    \fi}

\def\xxomino#1{%
    \ifx\relax#1%
    \else
    \ifx\\#1%
    \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
    \count@\z@
    \else
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \ifx*#1%
    \put(\count@,-\@tempcntb){\kern-6pt\framebox(0.93,0.93)}
    \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\xxomino%
    \fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Polyominoes with two or more rows like this \omino{*****\\*\\*} 
work great, but polyominoes that have only one row like this 
\omino{******} don't align properly. 

Also, the first row needs to be complete, like this \omino{*...\\****} 
to work. Without the empty characters, the polyomino is not spaced 
correctly, like \omino{*\\****} this. 

\end{document}
```

[image]